AJAX Call in Node Service Takes 40+ Seconds While Same Backend Service Responds in 5 Seconds via Postman
I have a Node.js service that makes two AJAX calls to a backend server. The problem I'm facing is that the service takes more than 40 seconds to complete when accessed through an AJAX call from the frontend, but the same backend service responds within 5 seconds when tested directly using Postman. Below is the code for the Node.js service:
// ...
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`, new Date());
});

app.get('/api', (req, response, next) => {
    console.log(`[${new Date()}] API called...`);
    let user = md5(req.query.user+'mytest').substring(0,5)
    let secretcode = req.query.secretcode
    let type = req.query.type
    console.log(`[${new Date()}] User: ${user}, Secret Code: ${secretcode}, Type: ${type}`);
    if(user == secretcode) {
      console.log(`[${new Date()}] Initiating checkApiUser request...`);
      axios.post('http://192.168.xxx.xxx:xxxx/checkUser', qs.stringify({
        acUsername: req.query.user,
        acPassword: secretcode
      })).then(res => {
        console.log(`[${new Date()}] checkApiUser request completed.`);

        console.log(`[${new Date()}] Initiating apiCatalog request...`);
        axios.post('http://192.168.xxx.xxx:xxxx/catalog', qs.stringify({
          data1: res.data.data1,
          data2: res.data.data2,
          data3: req.query.data3 ? req.query.data3 : 0,
          data4: req.query.data4 && req.query.data4 == "some" || req.query.data4 == "other" ? 0 : 1,
          data5: req.query.data5 ? req.query.data5 : "",
          //...
        })).then(resp => {
          console.log(`[${new Date()}] apiCatalog request completed.`);
          let products = resp.data.product;
          if(type == "xml") {
            response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            return response.send(o2x({
                '?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?' : null,
                catalog: {
                    product: products
                }
            }));
          } else {
            return response.json({catalog: products})
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    }
});


Here are the logs:
[Wed May 29 2024 14:02:47 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] API called...
[Wed May 29 2024 14:02:47 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] User: sample, Secret Code: 34sdg, Type: undefined
[Wed May 29 2024 14:02:47 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] Initiating checkApiUser request...
[Wed May 29 2024 14:02:47 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] checkApiUser request completed.
[Wed May 29 2024 14:02:48 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] Initiating apiCatalog request...
[Wed May 29 2024 14:03:34 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] apiCatalog request completed.

What could be causing this significant delay in the AJAX call from the frontend compared to using Postman? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.
Postman SC:


I’m a bit confused, you say requests made to a local host endpoint behave differently, but we don’t know anything about that endpoint or the Postman request made to it?

so the logs show that the request to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:xxxx/checkUser is quick, but the request to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:xxxx/catalog takes a long time? As the previous comment says, how can we know why the unknown server does that P.S. no need to hide private IP addresses, just makes the code less readable

But you are not showing anything about the /catalog code, there is no way for us to tell what could make it slow.

@JaromandaX No, http://192.168.xxx.xxx:xxxx/catalog takes 40+ seconds requested from axios, but from Postman it takes 5sec. I am working on a frontend part and have no access to backend code. In Postman I am requesting POST with raw JSON in body to the same endpoint

oh, that's odd, you must do something different in postman compared to the code you've shown

@JaromandaX Pardon: In Postman I am requesting POST with Query Params

Ahh ... well, you should do that then

If Postman and your frontend are doing different things, and get different timings and this confuses you, then your question should be about those different things, not which client is making them as this gives no context to what may be going on.

@Evert Isn't that what I asked in the end: What causes the delay on frontend compared to Postman?

@JaromandaX I did, ant it's the same result
[Mon Jun 03 2024 12:15:12] Initiating apiCatalog request... [Mon Jun 03 2024 12:15:58] apiCatalog request completed.

your postman screenshot and the code look like they use different data
